# copying column from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to copy a column from one table to another. The problem is matching the values with the right rows.

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTable (money_owed)
SELECT "credit"
FROM SourceTable
```

How do I search through the destination table and compare another field to see if it's the same one in the source table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/sql-server-update-from-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the two tables on the matching condition.

Something like this

```
UPDATE
   DestinationTable 
SET 
   DestinationTable.money_owed = SourceTable.Credit
FROM
   DestinationTable 
INNER JOIN SourceTable
ON DestinationTable.Field2 = SourceTable.Field2
```

Answer (score 0):

do an Update from:

```
UPDATE
    destination
SET
    destination.money_owed = source.Credit
FROM
    destination
INNER JOIN
    source
ON
    source.id = destination.id
```